# difference between "как это устроено" and "как это работает"

Tags: словоупотребление, выражения, лексикон

What is the difference between "**как это устроено**" and "**как это работает**"?
Both mean "how it works"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is literal

**`как это устроено (?)`** - how it's built (how is it built?)

**`как это работает (?)`** - how it works (how does it work?)

**`как это устроено`** can at times be used to mean **`how does it work?`** when one asks to be shown the way something works which involves engaging numerous controls in specific sequences.

Comment: Or in short, first question is about `structure`(static characteristics) and second about `behaviour`(dynamic characteristics).